# How to change the wick/shadow color for candlestick_ohlc

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an attribute to set candlestick wick/shadow/border colour?

I have set 'colordown' to black. The problem is that the plot's background colour is also black. As a result, the down bar blends into the background.

If I can somehow change the border colour of candlestick I can get the desired outcome I am looking for. Is there an attribute I can set to do this?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('k')
candlestick_ohlc(ax, tuples, width=.6, colorup='w', colordown='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to figure this out. I had to change the matplot.finance module. I candlesticks are created by two panels. Line2D and Rectangle. Both objects have a line/edgecolor you can modify. I passed in 'white'. You also need to change the zorder of the Line2D and Rectangle. So that the line appears behind the Rectangle. Thx

Comment: My only fear is that I did this in the main Matplotlib.finance module. Is there a way to override this using a file in my working directory and not it site-packages?